# jQuery autosuggest only working on one of two fields

Tags: jquery, .net, autosuggest

I would like to have two textfields with the jquery autosuggest plugin.

It is working just fine with the first field:
**Call:**

```
$("#cphContent_txtCity").autocomplete({ source: "ClassLibrary/Cities.aspx", minLength: 2, select: function (event, ui) { } });
```

**Reply:**`["Munchberg","Muncheberg","Munchen","Munchenbernsdorf","Munchendorf","Munchhouse","Munchsmunster"]`

After that I've added a second field (copy with different sql statement):
**Call:**

```
$("#cphContent_txtExpertise").autocomplete({ source: "ClassLibrary/Expertises.aspx", minLength: 2, select: function (event, ui) { } });
```

**Reply:**

```
["Acupressure","Acupuncture"]
```

When I check with firebug I can see that both fields trigger the call, but only the first field (cities) will give the suggestions.

I really can't see anything wrong with it. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the second autocomplete is returning a 'value' or 'label' field so jquery knows what to show. From the documentation:

> “The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties, the value will also be used as the label.”

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. But why is the first field working then? :)

Comment: It's probably treating it as if it were a simply array.

Comment: And it works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/vv2y9/1/ Something other than the autocomplete maybe.

Comment: Hmm... That's really weird. I think I'll just try it on a blank page to see if it works there...